# What to perfer scroll view or collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create film strip type view having tumbnail images and label having image names. By tapping on thumbnail image large image should get open. I am getting little confuse what should I prefer to use scrollview or collectionview.

Comment: Can at least one in this thread enriches his answer with an explanation, why he prefers one of the views?

Answer (score 0):

Use Collectionview as it is specifically designed for requirements as u told.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
//write your code here just like tableview
return 3;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//configure your cells here
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
// this method for handling your selection of particular cell
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5; // This is the minimum inter item spacing, can be more
}
```

Answer (score -1):

CollectionView in swift 3...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//write your code here just like tableview
return 3
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //configure your cells here
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // this method for handling your selection of particular cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionView, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
    // This is the minimum inter item spacing, can be more
}
```